# Run Portrait Video Output Pre-X Server

Tags: linux, video, xorg

I know it's possible to rotate video output in X server to display in portrait mode as well as landscape.

I'm curious if it's possible to rotate the video output that occurs pre-X server. The white text on black background output as the machine boots (rc.sysinit, bringing up eth connections, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the framebuffer-console you can use the `fbcon=rotate:n` command at boot time to rotate the console output.

(n = 0: no rotation, n=1 90deg clockwise, n=2 upside down, n=3: 90deg counterclockwise)

The framebuffer options are documented in the kernel source in the file

```
linux-source-2.6.32/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt
```